# How to reset/save $_SESSION variables in forms for each user?

Tags: 7, forms, users, sessions

I need to add captcha to *user login* form after 3 failed logins.

To do so I built the following module, and used `$_SESSION['failed_login']` to keep track of the number of the failed logins.

This module works well, but when I close the browser and test a failed login again, the number that is stored via `watchdog` will not reset again from `1`, it continues increasingly.

```
<?php 

function failed_login_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'user_login') {
        $form['#validate'][] = 'failed_login_myloginhandler';
    }
}

function failed_login_myloginhandler(&$form, &$form_state) {
    global $user;
    if (!$user->uid) {
        if(!$_SESSION['failed_login'])
            $_SESSION['failed_login'] = 0;
        $_SESSION['failed_login']++;
        watchdog("error", $_SESSION['failed_login']);
    }
}
```

What is the problem? Why it is not reset from `1` again? How can I have this temporary variable for each user who is trying to login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Drupal's sessions are kept for about 23 days. You can modify this in settings.php. Look for gc_maxlifetime and cookie_lifetime to reduce it to 0 so sessions are destroyed when the browser is closed.

This will effect logged in users too so when they close the browser they will also be logged out.

On a side note if you were unaware drupal already have flood control and will block IPs for multiple failed login attempts

Comment: Thank you. So you mean it is unnessecary to add captcha for login form?

Comment: Yeah I'd say it's not really nessessary but you might want to add the honeypot module to your site. https://www.drupal.org/project/honeypot It adds a hidden field so no normal user will populate it but a bot probably would so it can stop these submissions similar to captcha but without the annoyance to users